# How can I cause a while statement that takes integer input to respond in certain ways to non-integer input?

Tags: c++, while-loop, int

I am trying to create a while loop within a simple test program. This program is meant to sum all the integers that are entered by the user, and to display this sum and exit the loop after the user presses "a." If the user enters something other than an integer or "a," the program is meant to respond "Invalid input. Please try again" and allow the user to enter a different number.

My program successfully sums up integers, but if a non-integer other than "a" is entered, the loop ends without allowing the user to enter in a different value. The block of code starting with if (!cin) doesn't seem to be doing anything.

I think the issue is with `(!cin)` and not with `test = to_string(number)`. Is there an alternative method to detecting a non-integer that would allow this program to succeed?

Here is the program. Thank you as always for your help!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main()
{
int sum = 0;
int number;
string test;
cout << "Enter a series of integers; when you are done entering these integers, press a to display the sum of all integers.\n";
while (cin >> number)
{if (!cin)
    {
    test = to_string(number);
    if (test == "a")
        {break;}
    else 
        {cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n";
        continue;}
}
else 
{sum += number;}
}

cout << "The total sum is " << sum << ".\n";

}
```

Comment: 1. There are more than one problem in your program. For instance, the while condition will fail if you do not input an integer. 2. You can read one character. If the character is ‘a’ break the loop, else put it back in stream and try to read an integer. See `putback`, `unget` or `peek`.

Comment: Thank you for the response zdf. A couple follow-up questions:
1. So if I enter a non-integer into the while loop, will the loop always immediately break without the code regarding "a" being checked?
2. Might the solution then be to create an infinite for loop and turn the while (cin >> number) statement into an if (cin >> number) statement? I edited my original question to show this possible answer.
3. Just as a note, I'm not sure that reading a character would be the best solution, since I also want the program to be able to handle erroneous string entries in place of integers.

Comment: 1. Yes, since `cin >> number` (number is of type int), the while is checking the truth of int.
2. An infinite loop is never the best case, since if we fail to handle the condition where it have to break then it goes on continously.

Comment: `while` statements execute statements in a loop. They don't 'take integer input' or 'respond ... to non-integer input'. That is solely the preserve of the statements they control, which you have to *write*. The `while` statement has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

See inline comments for details:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

int main()
{
int sum = 0;
char ch; // Since we can't know whether user inputs an int or char
cout << "Enter a series of integers; when you are done entering these integers, press a to display the sum of all integers.\n";
while (cin) // Loop until user inputs
{
    cin >> ch;

if (isalpha(ch)) // Check if input is type char and handle as needed
{   
    if (ch == 'a')
        {
            break;
        }
    else 
        {
            cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n";
            std::cin.clear(); // Delete the current stream
            std::cin.ignore(32767,'\n'); // Revert back to previous input
            continue;
        }
}
else 
{
    sum += (ch - '0') % 48; // Since we are converting the char to int, handle it properly

}
}
cout << "The total sum is " << sum << ".\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for noting that while (cin) can work. By following while (cin) with if (cin >> number), I think I've arrived on a solution that works for me. Your conversion of characters to integers is intriguing, however.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that combines a program from Phillip Siedler's Bumpy Road to Code blog (https://bumpyroadtocode.com/2017/07/11/sum-of-integer-range/) with Lakshmi's use of `while (cin).`

This seems to allow the program to break if "a" is entered, and to enter the invalid input message and allow the user to try again if something other than an integer or "a" is entered.

I'm somewhat mystified as to why `cin.clear()` followed by `cin >> test` works. If you clear `cin`, how is there something in `cin` for the `cin >> test` line to pick up on? Perhaps I'm not understanding exactly what `cin.clear()` does.

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>
//Solution borrows significantly from Philipp Siedler's solution for Chapter 5 Exercise 8 of Programming Practice and Principles: https://bumpyroadtocode.com/category/chapter-05-principles-and-practice-using-c/ 


int main()
{
int sum = 0;
int number;
string test;
cout << "Enter a series of integers; when you are done entering these integers, press a to display the sum of all integers.\n";

while (cin)
{
if (cin >> number)
{sum += number;}
else 
 {cin.clear();
    cin >> test;
    if (test == "a")
        {break;}
    else 
        {
        cout << "Invalid input. Please try again.\n";
        continue;}
  }

}

cout << "The total sum is " << sum << ".\n";


}
```